# PowerShell. Setting ShowWithoutActivation property of System.Windows.Forms.Form

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm trying to create a form via powershell with following code

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
#adding some properties
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form)
```

It works fine, but I need to create a form without stealing focus of currently active window. In Microsoft's documentation I've found ShowWithoutActivation property. I'm setting it this way:

```
$form | Add-Member ScriptProperty 'ShowWithoutActivation' {return $true}
```

But it doesn't work. Now property returns true, but new form steals focus anyway.

Comment: `$form.Add_Shown({ $this.SendToBack() })` before your `Run` should be it

Comment: Override `CreateParams` to set the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` Style (as you have to override `ShowWithoutActivation`). Probably better if you execute C# code in a `$code = @' ... '@` block.

Comment: @Jimi
thanks. but is there a way to override it via powershell?